# Multimap intelligent sorting by key

Tags: c++, sorting, multimap, accumulate

I have been working on this problem for sometime now. I have 3 .txt files containing some stuff to read in and arrange within a multimap,

```
std::multimap<std::string, std::multimap<int, int>>
```

but if the key already exists, I increment the value and if the key is unique, I put the value in the map.

The 3 .txt files (labelled "x," "y," and "z") contain this:

"x.txt" contains primary keys:

```
a a a b b b c c c d d d e e e
```

"y.txt" contains secondary keys:

```
1 2 2 3 4 4 5 4 4 2 6 6 6 6 6
```

and "z.txt," which counts the secondary keys, contains:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The desired output is this:

```
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 1
4 : 2
5 : 1
4 : 2
2 : 1
6 : 2
6 : 3
```

Which states that there is one 1 in a, two 2's in a, one 3 in b, two 4's in b... and so on.

My code (below) incorrectly produces this result:

```
1 : 1
2 : 1
2 : 1
2 : 1
3 : 1
4 : 1
4 : 1
5 : 1
6 : 1
6 : 1
6 : 1
```

Here is the code: Any suggestions?

```
//needed to output your result (print map)
template<typename a, typename b>
void print1(const std::multimap<a, b>& thing){
    for (std::multimap<a,b>::const_iterator it = begin(thing); it != thing.end(); it++){
        std::cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
}


std::ifstream X("x.txt");
std::ifstream Y("y.txt");
std::ifstream Z("z.txt");


typedef std::multimap<int, int> Y_Z;
typedef std::multimap<std::string, Y_Z> X_Y_Z;

typedef std::pair<int, int> pair_y_z;
typedef std::pair<std::string, Y_Z> pair_x_y_z;

Y_Z y_z;
X_Y_Z x_y_z;

std::string x_;
int y_;
int z_;


if (X){
    while (X >> x_, Y >> y_, Z >> z_){

        if (x_y_z.empty()) {
            y_z.insert(pair_y_z(y_, z_));
            x_y_z.insert(pair_x_y_z(x_, y_z));
        }
        else {

            X_Y_Z::iterator first_iter = x_y_z.find(x_);
            X_Y_Z::iterator last_iter = x_y_z.upper_bound(x_);

            if (x_y_z.find(x_) == x_y_z.end()) {
                y_z.insert(pair_y_z(y_, z_));
                x_y_z.insert(pair_x_y_z(x_, y_z));
            }
            else{
                for (; first_iter != last_iter; first_iter++){
                    if (x_y_z.find(x_)->second.find(y_) == x_y_z.find(x_)->second.end()){
                        //no match
                        y_z.insert(pair_y_z(y_, z_));
                        x_y_z.insert(pair_x_y_z(x_, y_z));
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        //found match
                        x_y_z.find(x_)->second.find(y_)->second += z_;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

std::cin.get();
print1(y_z);
std::cin.get();
```

Comment: @Kerrek: He's shown the current and desired outputs, which is one of the ways we encourage clarifying the problem.  I still don't understand what role the primary key plays here.

Comment: Even with that, it's not clear what problem the OP is trying to solve.  What's the point of the third (z.txt) file?

Comment: A map won't work for this, your output requires that `5 : 1` for `c` is presented before the `4 : 2` for `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So. It's totally not clear why you are hurting yourself with this complicated data structure. You've got a key with two parts. So let's make the key to your `std::map` a `std::pair<T1, T2>`.

If we do that, the code becomes incredibly simple.

### Source Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::ifstream X("x.txt");
    std::ifstream Y("y.txt");
    std::ifstream Z("z.txt");

    std::map<std::pair<std::string, int>, int> data;

    std::string x_;
    int y_;
    int z_;

    while (X >> x_, Y >> y_, Z >> z_)
        data[std::make_pair(x_, y_)] += z_;

    for (auto const & element : data)
        std::cout << std::get<1>(element.first) << " : " << element.second << "\n";
}
```

### Output:

```
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 1
4 : 2
4 : 2
5 : 1
2 : 1
6 : 2
6 : 3
```

### Further issues:

There is one discrepancy between my output and the desired output, but I think it's an error in what you expect.

Your current output expects:

```
{a, 1} : 1
{a, 2} : 2
{b, 3} : 1
{b, 4} : 2
{c, 5} : 1  <--- note that this key is out of order with the next one. 5 > 4.
{c, 4} : 2
{d, 2} : 1
{d, 6} : 2
{e, 6} : 3
```

But I'm assuming that the keys should all be sorted properly, which is what my output does.

Comment: You said: "You've got a key with two parts. So let's make the key to your std::map a std::pair<T1, T2>." <--this is pretty cool IMO. This is incredibly elegant and is exactly the solution I was looking for. Your result is even better than the result I gave (ordered correctly). I have one more question: would it be possible to modify the map (decrement values of z) using conditions checking both parts of the key?

Comment: Yes, you could. Do you have an example of such a condition?

Comment: Well, not anything concrete yet. But something that goes like this: there is a similar (larger/smaller) map called data2 which has exactly the same types (string, int, int) and looks like data2[std::make_pair(a, b)] = c. I want to use int 'c' in data2 to modify int 'z' in data1 if int 'b' matches int 'y.' Like: If (std::get<1>(data1.first) == data2.first) { z -= c; } something crazy like that.

Comment: A `std::map` or a `std::multimap` with the current key doesn't allow you to do that very efficiently. If you swapped the key such that it was `{b, a} -> c`, then I think you could. Most likely, you would iterate over `data2`, and then look to see if anything in `data1` matched it, if so, perform your decrement operation. Likely it would look like: `for (...) for (...) if (...) perform_operation;`

Comment: I think I can make that work. However, any idea as to how I can access 'z' to decrement (or even delete) it? I am used to using map::find to iterate through maps, but I am a little confused when the map has a "dual" key like this.

Comment: When you use find, the resulting type is `std::pair<std::pair<std::string, int>, int>`. So ` x == iterator->first.first`, `y == iterator->first.second`, and `z == iterator->second`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your problem description that calls for a multimap.  Just use `std::map` instead.

Also, get rid of `y_z`.  Every time you use it, it appears that you should be using `x_y_z[x]`.

Comment: I ran towards using a multimap because I thought I needed it for the appearance of duplicate keys. But it turns out I could use a pair<> of elements as a single key